# Web3 Websocket Connection To Infura Rinkeby Ropsten

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, ethereumjs

This is my Javascript code. I keep getting an error that states

> (node:30062) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
>   privateKey.startsWith is not a function

I am using node 12.1.0 & web3^1.0.0-beta.55

```
   const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(_ABI);

   web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add({
        address:_publicKey,
        privateKey: _privateKey
    });
    const contract_Instance = await contract.deploy({
        data: _bytecode,
        arguments: _constructor_args})
        .send({
        from: _adminAddress,
        gas: 1500000,
        gasPrice: '20000000000'
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `_privateKey` should be a string.

Comment: I changed _privateKey to _privateKey.toString() & now I get this error:   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No privateKey given to the TransactionSigner.

Comment: `address` should be the account's address, not the account's public key. And then `from` should be that same address (I'm not sure what `_adminAddress` is).

Comment: _adminAddress is the _publicKey. How do I get the account's address?

Comment: How did you get the public key?

Comment: It's a function parameter.

Comment: Well, then pass the address to that function too.

Comment: I got it to work. However, `await contract.deploy(...)` successfully executes the txn (I verified on etherscan) but it does not return a contract object. When I tried switching to .on("confirmation") the confirmation was called roughly every 30 seconds until the network connection timed out. How do I fix this?