# How to deploy Smart Contracts With Web3 Using Async/Await?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, ethereumjs

This is my Javascript code. I keep getting an error that states

> Error: No privateKey given to the TransactionSigner.
>       at TransactionSigner._callee$ (/Users/payton/WebstormProjects/Esgro_DAPP/node_modules/web3-eth/dist/web3-eth.cjs.js:53:23)
>       at tryCatch (/Users/payton/WebstormProjects/Esgro_DAPP/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/payton/WebstormProjects/Esgro_DAPP/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
>       at Generator.prototype. [as next] (/Users/payton/WebstormProjects/Esgro_DAPP/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)

I am using node 12.1.0 & web3^1.0.0-beta.55

```
 const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(_ABI);

   web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add({
        address:_publicKey,
        privateKey: _privateKey.toString()
    });
    const contract_Instance = await contract.deploy({
        data: _bytecode,
        arguments: _constructor_args})
        .send({
        from: _adminAddress,
        gas: 1500000,
        gasPrice: '20000000000'
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/71081/16043), which you posted earlier. Please don't spam this facility with multiple questions that look the same.

Comment: The one I posted earlier had the wrong title & I was worried that it would not be addressed. Thank you for being diligent.

Answer (score 1):

With web3 v1.0.0-beta.34, you can use this:

```
async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs) {
    const abi = fs.readFileSync(YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH + contractName + ".abi");
    const bin = fs.readFileSync(YOUR_ARTIFACTS_PATH + contractName + ".bin");
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    const options = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs};
    const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
    const handle = await send(transaction);
    const args = transaction.encodeABI().slice(options.data.length);
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}

async function send(transaction) {
    const options = {
        to   : transaction._parent._address,
        data : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas  : (await util.web3.eth.getBlock("latest")).gasLimit
    };
    const signedTransaction  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
    return transactionReceipt;
}
```